# Populate a vector in Matlab using a smaller vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I need to populate a vector with elements of another, smaller vector. So say the vector I need to populate is of length ten and is currently all zeros, i.e.

```
vector = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Now suppose I have already define a vector

```
p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How could I populate "vector" with the array "p" so that the result is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`? Bear in mind, I want the other positions in "vector" to remain unchanged. I have already tried using `repmat(p, length(p))` but that ends up giving me something of the form `[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Answer (score 5):

<s>Try a combination of [vector slicing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) and [concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html):</s>

```
vector = cat(1, p, vector(5:))
```

This is faster:

```
vector(1:5) = p
```

More generally,

```
vector(1:numel(p)) = p
```

Comment: The first option is incorrect. The second option is the standard way to do this.

Comment: The second option here is the way to go.  It can be generalized a bit further too for differing size of of p like this `vector(1:numel(p)) = p;`